# Status of conjecture of Conrey and Gonek, combinatorial meaning

Tags: nt.number-theory, young-tableaux

I was looking at the OEIS on the [number of square Young Tableaux](https://oeis.org/A039622).

In it Michael Somos referenced a paper of Conrey and Gonek, [High Moment's of the Riemann Zeta-Function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9902162.pdf). Is there an combinatorial interpretation of equation $(19)$ on page 8 in the paper?

I'm trying to piece one together, but I have a minuscule knowledge about number theory. The coefficient $\frac{g_k}{k^2!}$ is the probability that a $k$ by $k$ grid of $k^2$ distinct numbers is a young tableaux. The probability that $k^2$ numbers of size $N$ are all prime is $\log^{-k^2}(N)$, so it sort of looks like a conditional probability?  Is there a simple interpretation of what $a_k$ (equation 10 on page $4$) means?

Comment: Can you please state your question in a self-contained way, without making people read stuff from other links?

Comment: A related question is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248784.